# Getting indices of sorted elements of matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting

I am trying to get the sort of row and column according to the value of matrix.
for example, if the matrix is

```
A = [3 4 7; 9 8 6; 2 1 5]
```

it should output

```
2 1
2 2
1 3
2 3
3 3 
1 2
1 1
3 1
3 2
```

I think that should be simple, but I do not have an idea about how to handle that.

Comment: I have changed the title of your question to better reflect the question. Please feel free to replace it if you don't find it apt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is indeed very simple.

```
%sort the vector instead of matrix to get linear indices
[~,ind]=sort(A(:),'descend')  

%convert the linear indices to [row,col] subscripts
[I,J]=ind2sub(size(A),ind)

%display desired answer 
[I J]
```

To delete rows which have same value in both the columns:

```
A(A(:,1)==A(:,2),:)=[]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your wonderful response. Another simple question. How to delete rows, in which inside the rows, it have same value, for example, A = [1, 1; 2, 3; 4 ,4], I would like to delete row one and three. Thanks!

Comment: @ivory `A([1 3],:) = [];` will do I think. But do pay attention to the dimension and index changes! :)

Comment: @ivory please show your efforts next time when you ask question on stackoverflow

Comment: @ivory And remember to accept the answer if it does what you want